# Is there a way in java to send an object to another classes method from inside the objects class?

Tags: java, class, methods

For example I have a driver and two classes, `classA` and `classB`. `If classA` has a variable that is an object from `classB`, and `classB` has a variable from `classA`. Would it be possible in a `method1` in `classA` to switch the `classB`'s variable of the `classA` variable to equal the `classA` object that the `method1` was called from?

```
public class driver { 
    private classA a = new classA();
    private classA b = new classB(a), c = new classB();
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        a.set (b);
        a.set (c);
}    

public class classA {
    private classB var = null;
    public classA() {}
    public void set (classB b) {
        if (var != null)
            var.remove();
        var = b;
        var.set( /*code to send this a to var*/);
    }
}

public class classB {
    private classA var = null;
    public classA() {}
    public void set (classA a) {
        var = a;
    }
    public void remove() {
        var = null;
    }
}
```

What would I replace  `/*code to send this a to var*/` with? Would `this` work?

Comment: Code is a bit clunky, and you might want to ask yourself whether you really need a cyclical reference, but yeah, `this` will work.

Comment: `remove` is not necessary

Comment: why is remove not neccesary

Comment: By changing the `var` to point to another instance of `classA`, the reference to the previous instance of `classA` will be removed. When an object is no longer referenced, it will automatically be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Because `var.remove(); var.set(a);` is logically equivalent to `var.var = null; var.var = a;`.